# Use nohup to run a long process in docker at a remote server

Tags: docker, ssh, nohup

I used to run a long training process on a remote server with GPU capabilities. Now my work schedule changes, so I can't have my computer connected to a network all the time till I finish the process. I found that `nohup` is the solution for me. But I don't know how to keep invoke the process correctly related my situation.

1. I use `ssh` to connect to the remote server.
2. I have to use docker to access to GPU.
3. Then I start the process in the docker.

If I start the process with `nohup` in docker, I can't really leave docker, right. So, do I use `nohup` at each step?

**Edit:**
I need the terminal output of the process at step 3, because I need that information to carry out the rest of the work. Consider, step 3 is training a neural network. So, the training log tells me the accuracy of different models at different iterations. I use that information to do the testing.

Comment: The Docker container should _be_ the process – there shouldn't be a "start the process in Docker" step – and you can use `docker run -d` to launch the container in the background.

Comment: So, I have to include the start-the-process in my docker file, so that I could get ridof it. But I do need the output of the process run inside docker. That output tells me which model I should use for testing.

Comment: It will be in the `docker logs` of the container, until you `docker rm` it.

Comment: You might get along better with `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

Following @David Maze's suggestion, I did this (a slightly different approach as I was not familiar with docker a whole lot)

1. Logged in to the remote server.
2. Configured the docker script to have remote workdir.

```
...
WORKDIR /workspace
...
```

3. After building the docker container, run docker with mount option to mount the local project to docker `workdir`.  When running docker, I used `nohup`. Since I don't need interactive mode I ignored the `-it` flag.

```
nohup docker run --gpus all -v $(pwd)/path-to-project-root:/workspace/ docker-image:tag bash -c "command1; command2" > project.out 2>&1 &
```

To test this, I logged out from the server and see the content of project.out later. It contained the expected output.

Comment: Just FYI, a lot of people write `cmd > logfile 2>&1` to redirect `stdout` to a logfile, then redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, but there is a convenient and more readable shortcut : `cmd &> logfile`